# Limitations and capabilities of a mobile framework for app development

Tags: jquery, cordova, extjs

Ok guys, let me preface my question with this, This is not a technical question per say but relates to app development, frameworks and support that I can't quite seem to figure out anywhere else on the web.

So my company has tasked me to become an "expert" at developing iPad apps for our clients (Pharma, nothing crazy). So my background is in web development, front and back end. I've looked into native (would take way too long for me to get comfortable) and I've played with sencha and JQtouch in the past. What I learned is that frameworks tend to restrict you to doing things a certain way.

What I'm asking is, If I wanted to develop an app with a custom designed layout, similar to http://asidemag.com/ Would you still recommend developing this within a framework or building it with standard programing, I.E. jQuery, Javascript, etc. What are the major developers of iPad/HTML5 apps using? I'm really just stuck thinking that I'm limited in capabilities developing with a framework but what scares me about no framework is the stability.

What do you experts do? what do you recommend?

Comment: Using paragraphs greatly improves the readability of your question. The `Did your return-key stop working?` was just a joke. I even removed the comment after I noticed you edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main advantage to a mobile frameworks is the time/effort the author(s) put into UI widgets.

The question boils down to: do you have processes associated with your application that can't be handled within a specific framework? If not then you probably want to save yourself time by not re-inventing the wheel and use a framework to handle the nitty-gritty.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, what your saying is definitely a valid consideration. Have you worked with Sencha? do you know how difficult it is to modify a theme or elemental structure? thanks!

Comment: I use jQuery Mobile, which has an awesome themeroller tool to create your own theme swatches: http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/.